How to send voice in expo chat
I use Google Translate to write
question
I wrote a chat page for two people. I want to implement the function of sending voice in WeChat. When you long press the recording voice button, you can send voice to the other party. The backend uses nodejs and mongoDB database, and uses socket.Io for connection. The frontend is a page built by expo.
I am using an Android phone. I clicked on the recording button and an audio file was generated after recording. It was saved in the album. This path is the real path. I want the program to automatically obtain the real path and store it in the database, but the program cannot obtain the path. I want to send the file directly to the database or convert it into an http path on the front end.
Please help me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
